# Feathers - Emit Custom Event via Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I am trying to emit a custom event in a Feathers hook. I tried the following in the hook:

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return async context => {

    const { app } = context;

    const groupsService = app.service('groups');
    const groups = await groupsService.find( { query:{ members: context.result.user._id } });
    
    await app.emit('list', groups); // Try 1
    await groupsService.emit('list', groups); // Try 2
    await context.service.emit('list', groups); // Try3
    console.log('====================EMIT====================');

    return context;
  };
};
```

I also added the event to the service:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  this.events = ['list']; // Try 1
  (...)
  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('groups');

  service.events = ['list']; // Try 2

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

The problem is, that the event never gets emitted. With debugging I only see the following messages in the console:

> debug: before app.service('groups').find()
>
> debug: after app.service('groups').find()
>
> ====================EMIT====================

However the event is never emitted using Socket.io. In the channels I send every event to authenticated users. I also tried changing it to everybody without success. As I run Feathers using `DEBUG=* npm start` I can see, that the event is never emitted. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still a little finicky at the moment. The problem is that the `events` array needs to be on the service when `app.use` is called. This can be done like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  (...)

  app.use('/groups', Object.assign(createService(options), {
    events: [ 'list' ]
  }));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('groups');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Then you can use it [as documented](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html#custom-events):

```
groupsService.emit('list', groups)
```

The Feathers database services already take an [`events` option](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#serviceoptions) so it would look like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const options = {
    (...)
    events: [ 'list' ]
  };

  app.use('/groups', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('groups');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found this issue with a code example from you which helped me: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/855 For everybody with the same problem, I implemented a custom event as described in the issue here: https://github.com/martinpfannemueller/feathers-chat